# How to reload Node.JS app without losing current open requests?

Tags: node.js, deployment, pm2

I'm using pm2 to reload my app but in my test the active requests are cancelled by the reload.

I tested by making an endpoint with an await of 10 seconds, requesting a response to this endpoint with Insomnia and then, before the 10 seconds await completes, reloading the app with pm2 reload . But what happens is that the pm2 reload stops the Insomnia request, which finishes as "Error: Server returned nothing (no headers, no data)".

Am I doing something wrong? Was not pm2 supposed to identify current running requests on await state? It could be a real production request where the app was waiting for a database response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch the `SIGTERM` signal from within your node.js/express application:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  console.info('SIGTERM signal received.');
  console.log('Close http server.');
  server.close(() => {
    console.log('Http server closed.');
    // You can close here other things that needs to, for example a mongodb/mongoose connection
    mongoose.connection.close(false, () => {
      console.log('MongoDb connection closed.');
      process.exit(0);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: But how closing my database will help my current active requests being answered?

Comment: HTTP closing is handle by `server.close(() => {`. Scheme is 
1 - intercept SIGTERM signal
2 - Close gracefully http server
3 - Close database connections (Mongo, Mysql, etc.)
This code assume your http server is called `server``

Comment: Thanks! I added increasing kill timeout to your solution and my problem was solved.
pm2 increase kill timeout: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/signals-clean-restart/